Difference between the two forms of derivates
Can anyone explain the difference between these two forms of derivatives:
f^(1,0)

and
D[f,x]

where  f = f[x,y]? From the application in a Mathematica file, I see that they are not giving the same result, but I do not understand clearly the difference between the two functions.

Did you read tutorial?

You can use f'[x], or f[x_]:= x^2; D[f[z],z]; or df = Derivative[1][f]; df[q] or Derivative[1][t] but I f^(1,0) is not valid syntax.  Seed examples in the Derivative documentation for details on mixed partials.

D[f[x, y], x] is an abbreviated input form for Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y] they are stored identically. Look at D[f[x, y], x] === Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y]

The difference is derivative wrt to a symbol name as contrasted to the derivative wrt to a slot
 D[f[a x, b x],x] = a Derivative[1,0][f][a x, b x] + b Derivative[0,1][f][a x, b x] 

 Derivative[n,m][f] 

is a pure function denoting $\nabla_1^n \nabla_2^m f$ as a map,
that can be supplied with any sequence of arguments.
      Derivative[n,m][f]@Sequence[e^x, Sin[y]] == 
        Function[{x,y}, D[f[x,y],{x,n},{y,n}][e^x, Sin[y]]


Thanks a lot for the clarification @Roland F
